# automatically set value for an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am working on a booking website using bootstrap datepicker, what i want to achieve is when a user choose a specific check-in date and number of nights, it sets an auto date value for the check-out date.

```js
 $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
 $(".check-in").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

<div class="booking">
  <input class="check-in" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input class="nights" type="number">
  <input class="check-out" data-provide="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date from check-in field. Then add that to the number on the input change (of the number field) by `setDate()`. Finally set that new date in the check-out field. Try the following:

```js
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
$(".check-in").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

$('.nights').on('input', function(){
  var date2 = $('.check-in').datepicker('getDate'); 
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + Number(this.value)); 
  $(".check-out").datepicker("setDate", date2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

<div class="booking">
  <input class="check-in" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input class="nights" type="number">
  <input class="check-out" data-provide="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with onchange !

```js
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    $(".check-in").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    function checkoutDate(){
       var date1 = $('.check-in').datepicker('getDate');
       var date = new Date( Date.parse( date1 ) );
       var nights = $('.nights').val();
       var count = parseInt(nights);
       date.setDate( date.getDate() + count);
       var newDate = date.toDateString();
       newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );
       $('.check-out').datepicker('setDate', newDate );
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<div class="booking">
 <input class="check-in" data-provide="datepicker" onchange="checkoutDate();">
 <input class="nights" type="number" onchange="checkoutDate();">
 <input class="check-out" data-provide="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange event. As soon as, the value of fields check-in date and number changes either you enter or focus out or click on datepicker. The check-out field will be updated.

```js
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
$(".check-in").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

$('.nights, .check-in').on('change', function(){
  var date2 = $('.check-in').datepicker('getDate'); 
  var no_days= $('.nights').val(); 
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + Number(no_days)); 
  $(".check-out").datepicker("setDate", date2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

<div class="booking">
  <input class="check-in" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input class="nights" type="number" min="0">
  <input class="check-out" data-provide="datepicker">
</div>
```